# Can node.js cluster clients receive deep objects or arrays in the forked environment?

Tags: javascript, node.js, fork

I am trying to pass an array of deep object like this:

```
data = [
    {
        "name": "foo",
        "data": [
            {
                "id"   : 1,
                "type" : "A",

            }
        ]
    },
    {
        "name": "bar",
        "data": [
            {
                "id"   : 2,
                "type" : "B",

            }
        ]
    },
];
```

to a forked cluster client in nodejs like so

```
cluster.fork({"stuff": data})
```

but the in the worker the object arrives as a string that looks like this when I console.dir() it.
'[object Object],[object Object]'

The [documentations](http://nodejs.org/api/cluster.html#cluster_cluster_fork_env) states

> cluster.fork([env])
>
> - env Object Key/value pairs to add to worker process environment.
> - return Worker object

I suspect that this means that cluster.fork can only take single level objects and the the deep object that I am passing in is getting cast. It makes sense but I can't seem to verify that this is truly the case.

My question is: Am I correct that cluster.fork can only take single level objects and regardless of whether I'm correct or not can someone point me to a reference that states it?

Thanks.

Comment: You may not be able to pass the data immediately when forking, but you can still use inter-process messaging via `worker.send` to send a copy of a JS object.

Comment: @loganfsmyth, I'm about to try worker.send(). I think that will be the best method. Thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Although it doesn't explicitly state this, `env` usually (especially in the context of starting new process; see [child_process.exec](http://nodejs.org/api/child_process.html#child_process_child_process_exec_command_options_callback) for another example) is used to set the environment variables.

Environment variables, if you're not familiar, are a UNIX concept of key/value pairs (where the keys and values are strings) that are usually inherited by spawned processes (although sometimes changed).

Comment: Thanks, I am familiar with Unix environment variables and was aware that they were key/value pairs. I'd forgotten or hadn't thought my way through to the fact that these were the environment variables making it to the new process (makes total sense now). I was also hoping that node.js would magically add super fun awesomeness and pass complex structures around for me so I didn't have to deal with it. Alas... I fear I must.

Comment: @crempp If your data is simple enough, you may be able to turn it into a JSON string and then parse it in the child process.

Comment: that's a great idea, I hadn't thought of that. My data is simple at the moment and this is a great solution. I expect my data will grow more complicated in the near future though.